# test GFCI tripped circuit in garage, would not reset, then power came back by itself later

Tags: electrical, gfci

In the garage, I've got two wall GFCI outlets, some other non-GFCI wall outlets, several overhanging lights, and a garage door opener. The conduits from these all comes together in a couple junction boxes up in the rafters.

I pressed Test on one of the GFCIs. It cut power to all the outlets and the door opener, but not to the overhead lights.

Then, when I pressed Reset nothing happened. There still wasn't any power. I went to the main panel. Nothing was tripped except for one circuit labelled "Hot tub" which doesn't feed the garage outlets (I don't actually know what this breaker feeds or whether it was already off before.) I tried flipping it on and off just in case, but it didn't help.

Then, about 10 or 15 minutes later, the power came back on by itself to the garage outlets. So I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on why it returned by itself?

The only things I can think of are a faulty GFCI which needed time to cool down before it could reset itself, or there is a subpanel somewhere whose breakers are auto-resettable.

I'd be curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Auto-resettable breakers are a bad idea, do you want one to reset when you are touching a hot wire.  Faulty GFCI is more likely.

Comment: Are any of the connections on the circuit in question "backstabbed"?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You mean where the connections to the outlet are plugged in through the holes instead of bending the wire and screwing them on? I have no idea, I would have to take out the outelts and switches and look at them .... Why would that cause the breaker to reset by itself after 10-15 minutes?

Comment: @crip659 I'm thinking faulty GFCI, but why would it come back on after 10-15min?

Comment: @MichaelMartinez -- backstabs have a bad habit of failing open under heavy load then coming good again as they cool off (eventually, they just fail open altogether if you keep cycling them)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Ok, that would explain it. I'll have to take off these GFCIs and inspect them and maybe replace them. Thanks for the info I didn't realize that. Actually I just wired up a GFCI in my bathroom and I backstabbed them in, maybe I redo that one too. I just hate bending the wires, they're so stiff and tough, do you have an tricks for making them more pliable?

Comment: @MichaelMartinez -- best trick is to get receptacles with screw-and-clamp connections that can safely be backwired (i.e. a "spec grade" receptacle instead of a home-store bargain-bin cheapie)